# Coldfusion 9 + SQL server 2008 datetime returns binary

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

I have a very simple query written in coldfusion 9. I have a datetime field that I am selecting, for some odd reason the query returns it as binary instead of as a date.

Is there a work around for this that does not require me to cast the date as a char.

Comment: Please post your query and any code.

Comment: Exactly which type of date you set in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using ToString(), then creating a Date/Time object using the CreateODBCDateTime() function...